# Как уменьшать отступы при уменьшении высоты окна браузера?

Tags: css

Есть страница, на которой футер прижат к низу.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <p>coming soon...</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Строительные магазины Сочи</li>
        <li>Товары для дома и ремонта</li>
        <li>Услуги мастеров</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="buffer"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-width: 320px;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

#wrapper {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 0 -75px 0;
    padding: 120px 7px 0 7px;
    min-height: 100%;
}

* html #wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}

.buffer {
    height: 75px;   
}

.logo {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 230px;
    height: 45px;
    background: url(../images/logo.png) center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

p {
    margin: 18px 0 118px 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: center; 
}

ul {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 60px 0 0 calc((100% - 305px)/2);
    height: 235px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}

li {
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 37px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #010101; 
}

li:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    left: 0;
}

li:first-child:before {
    background: #ff4131;
}

li:nth-child(2):before {
    background: #0086f8;
}

li:last-child:before {
    background: #00aa4b;
}

.footer {
    padding: 30px 7px;
    height: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 19px;
    color: #252525;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Как только весь контент перестает помещаться в область просмотра, появляется вертикальная полоса прокрутки. Как пропорционально уменьшать отступы (отмечены стрелками), чтобы избежать появления полосы прокрутки, чтобы она появлялась, когда отступы уже маленькие?

Comment: Сделайте код запускаемым, пожалуйста.

Comment: Знать бы, как это сделать.

Comment: В работе можно посмотреть тут https://jsfiddle.net/tw8q2yth/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Изменяя высоту окна браузера, вы можете проверить как это работает. Добавьте минимальную высоту блоку `.container__top` по вкусу, чтобы определить отступы для логотипа.

Суть метода: контейнер делается флексбоксом, в котором все элементы распологаются в колонку; блоку `.container__fix` задаётся `flex-grow: 1`, чтобы этот блок занял всё свободное место, также ему добавляется свойство `display: flex`, чтобы внутренний элемент можно было просто выровнять по вертикали и горизонтали; блоку `.logo` добавляется `margin: auto` чтобы выровнять его по вертикали и горизонтали.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container__fix {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
.container__top {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.container__footer {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
.logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__top">
    <div class="logo"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container__fix">
    fixed height menu
  </div>
  <div class="container__footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, это решение не кроссбраузерное? Не все браузеры поддерживают флексбокс.

Comment: Очень даже кроссбраузерное http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox